# there is no package called 'gridExtra'

Tags: r

I am getting the following error while trying to install `gridExtra` on my RStudio

```
install.packages('gridExtra')  - successfully installed
library(gridExtra) - not accessible error given below

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  internet routines cannot be loaded
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  internet routines cannot be loaded
Warning in install.packages :
  package 'gridExtra' is not available (for R version 3.4.1)
 Show Traceback
Error in library(gridExtra) : there is no package called 'gridExtra'
```

Comment: Dear PoGibas see there are packages available for gridExtra and I have been able to reinstall the packages with the dependencies set (pls refer the related post tagged for possible duplicate